Potentiostat for 5-6kW supply
I'm making a power supply with output around 2kV which can output 2-3 Amp of current. I want to use a potentiostat to keep voltage constant at output but I don't know how can I build it for such high powers.
May you suggest something what to do? Like using high rated IGBTs or something to improve the circuit.
I'm planning to use the little plasma arc generated at output in some experiment of electrochemistry. The spark gap will be submerged in an electrolyte which in this case will work as load, which will try to drop the voltage.
I want my circuit to give extra current to the circuit (which will be different for different electrolytes) to keep the voltage same.
There will be a third electrode for voltage reference in the electrolyte.
May you please explain what will be the best thing to do in this case?
It would be no issue if the accuracy is disturbed by 1 to 20 V.
The circuit I want to improve is this:

Source: "Understanding Potentiostats", Technical Note, Gamry Instruments, available online. Internet Archive memento.

What output accuracy do you need?

Why not use a potential divider, voltage reference and error amplifier to keep the output voltage constant. No need for a potentiostat unless you are not revealing something.

@winny Since I will be doing this for some PhD project, i want my results to be as accurate as possible.

@Andyaka I'm planning to use the little plasma arc generated at output in some experiment of electrochemistry. the spark gap will be submerged in an electrolyte which in this case will work as load, which will try to drop the voltage. i want my circuit to give extra current to the circuit (which will be different for different electrolytes) to keep the voltage same. there will be a third electrode for voltage reference in the electrolyte. May you please explain what will be the best thing to do in this case? since it will be for research purposes, i want to keep things as accurate as possible.

question: the spark, between which two elements of the schematic does that exist?

@MarcusMüller that would be between reference electrode and working electrode

For 20 V error, 0.1 % resistor divider and a 0.5 % reference will do without calibration.

@AkashJangra and to be clear, you want the voltage between the reference electrode and the working electrode to be constant? Or identical to some other voltage in the system?

@winny can you please explain it a little? i didn't get that.

@MarcusMüller first one would be better to say. I had 220V AC source that I stepped up using a microwave oven transformer. i added a capacitor in parallel to output and then rectified it using a single diode. so the signal generator in the diagram i provided is actually a source of half wave rectified voltage around 2kV peak. if my electrodes are at 2kV, I want them to stay at 2kV. Now you have the entire setup. please let me know what further info you need

I don't understand what you say there, sorry. your electrodes would never be constant at 2kV, because your voltage source is pulsing? And all this sounds pretty strange. Can you really go ahead and draw a schematic like the one you linked to, just showing your three-electrode cell, and marking between which points you want to have which voltage! I'm really a bit confused.

@MarcusMüller my apologies to create the confusion. when i said i want to keep the voltage constant, i meant by keeping its peak value constant. working electrode = at 2kV, reference electrode = at negligible (say 0.2- 1.0 V).

@AkashJangra really, please make a drawing and add it to your question. I'm sure you have a drawing on paper somewhere of this – after all, this is your PhD system – just take a clean photo of it and add that to your question :)

Arcs can be modelled as having a negative dynamic resistance.  After the arc is struck, if you maintain the voltage, the current will go up to very very high values. Typically arc based systems have strike voltage limits and current limits for the struck condition.
